# How to keyframe mesh vertices in Python without fcurve

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, keyframes

The code without adding the keyframe

```py
>>> c=bpy.data.objects["Z Function"]
>>> for f in range(100):
...     bpy.context.scene.frame_set(f)
...     for v in c.data.vertices:
...         v.co.z=np.sin((np.pi*f)*(v.co.x))+np.cos((np.pi*f)*(v.co.y))
...     # add keyframe for mesh vertice here
```

I tried using `ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="location",index=-1)` but didnt work because it probably keyframes the objects location and not the vertex's

I read [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36902/how-to-keyframe-mesh-vertices-in-python/36950#36950?newreg=27bfdbbcbf9843389b269c0d9139d846) and it looked a bit complex to me , is there no solution to keyframing mesh vertex without using fcurves ?

Another [thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111661/creating-shape-keys-using-python) used shapekeys to deform , but when I try add shape keys I get the following error
[image]

```py
>>> sk_basis = c.shape_key_add("Basis")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Object.shape_key_add(): required parameter "name" to be a keyword argument!
```

Comment: does it work if you try putting a keyword argument, like `name="Basis"`

Comment: Yeah but after that , I add shapekeys in the loop , but I still do not get the keyframes after running it 
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/439399976993292293/761992456350728233/blenderprob.gif

Comment: right, i think you know way more than i do :) the problem might be that the only thing you can keyframe is a shapekey's influence, not the shapekey itself

Comment: I see , I will look into that

Answer (score 1):

Vertices can be keyframed using the method `keyframe_insert` - pass the vertices you want to keyframe at a given frame in the function below.

```
def keyframe(vert, frame):
    for index in range(3):    
        vert.keyframe_insert("co", index=index, frame=frame, group="location")
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to do this without looping in python? It gets very slow with a large number of vertices

Comment: You can use 'foreach_set' directly on the fcurve. Checkout this link:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111644/fast-keyframe-insertion