# Add a first shape key where 'Basis' doesn't yet exist

Tags: shape-keys

I want to create a shape key `modifier_apply_as_shapekey(...)` where on a mesh where none yet exist, ie `myobj.data.shape_keys == None`, so `modifier_apply_as_shapekey()` will throw an error.

I'm not see the correct tree in the forest for something like a `new()` function.

Comment: Have you tried `myobj.shape_key_add(name = 'Basis')`? I've found it here: [Creating shape keys using Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/111661/107598)

Comment: @Blunder -- i'm glad I postponed pulling my hair out ... thanks!